# Show alert in observer

Tags: magento-1.9

how it's possible to show alert message (alert from javascript) in magento observer? I successfully registered an observer on event _customer_save_before_. Now I want only to show an alert in observer (for example "Hello user!").

Observer.php

```
<?php
class MyModule_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
  public function customerSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
  { 
     // TODO Need to show an alert here
  }
}
```

config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <customer_save_before>
            <observers>
                <MyModule>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>MyModule_Observer</class>
                    <method>customerSaveBefore</method>
                </MyModule>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

How to show an alert on the frontend in the simpliest way?
Thank you!

Comment: thanks for the comment, however that solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Observer methods run server side. Javascript runs on the client side.
You cannot show an alert from an observer.
Beside that, the customer save is usually made in an action that does have output.
For example `Mage_Customer_AccountController::createPostAction`. That method only registers the user and redirects back to the customer dashboard or to the previous page.

But what you can do is to set a value in the session and on the next page check if that value is present in the session and show your alert.

for example add this in your observer:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setShouldSayHello(true);
```

Now in one of your templates you can do this:

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getShouldSayHello(true)): //true means that the value will be removed from session after this call?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('Hello Sir!');
    </script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is it good solution? I need to find exact file in the design forlder and modify it. In case of changing design, I need to add such functionality always.

Comment: You can just create your own block and add it after the footer.

Comment: but I need to know the page, where I should add it. Or maybe I didn't understand you clear?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to alert the user?  Or are you using this for your own logging / troubleshooting purposes?  If the latter you should use magentos logging function.

```
Mage::log('Hello World!', null, 'mylogfile.log', true);
```

If the former I think your best bet would be to have a bit of logic that you would manipulate and pass back from your observer, once this manipulation occurs you can display a message on frontend.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I want to alert user on frontend, but not logging data